# why this code is printing 1, -1

Tags: c

Here is a code asked to me in an online test. Consider this code.

```
int i = -1, j = -1;
(i=0)&&(j=0);
(i++)&&(++j);
printf("%d, %d\n", i, j);
```

The above code will print

```
1, -1
```

Can somebody explain why the output is coming out to be `1, -1` and not `1, 1`.

Comment: Google for "short cicuit evaluation"

Comment: explain your own analysis of the code so far

Comment: @afzalex you know the answer already?

Comment: Yes, I discussed this question in chatroom and they find it very interesting and I thought I should post it to share knowledge. StackOverflow allow this. but I don't know why I am getting downvotes. I am gonna delete my question @thumbmunkeys

Comment: Why does somebody contemplate writing code that is incomprehensible, stupid and unmaintainable? Do they carry such a philosophy throughout their career?

Comment: @afzalex I haven't downvoted, but I'd like to know: have you ever seen anybody using such statements in code? And by this title no one who really used such "solution" will be able to solve their problems.

Comment: Now, write the same code exclusively using trigraphs. As long as we're making it hideous, may as well give it the full-monte.

Comment: Write decent code and you will not have so many problems

Comment: My question rather would be `why not`. Can you explain what output do you expect and why?

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited the code. I think it will be okay now.

Comment: 2 invalid close-votes already, and different ones...

Comment: Please somebody let me know why the question was bad and not interesting as I thought? @EdHeal

Comment: @afzalex - I could sit down and write bad code - code that is unreadable, incomprehensible, unmaintainable - a Friday afternoon job - but I choose to srubb it. I have bad thoughts but some things are better kept to your self

Comment: But I didn't wrote it myself, It was asked to me somewhere. and the site where I was asked this question was well reputated @EdHeal. I just tried to share knowledge, so that other who might not know how to solve it will gain understanding in this. But I cannot understand why are behaving so badly because of this question to me.

Comment: I would conclude that the site is very bad for your knowledge

Comment: It was [elance.com](https://www.elance.com). Believe me it is a very good site. Many companies try to use this site to find some employers, and many users with good knowledge tries to get a job there. It is a site for elancers. You cannot say it is a bad site. @EdHeal

Comment: @afzalex - It is a site for freelancers. Some may be good some may be bad. There is no guarantees.

Comment: From the [online help for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face.**"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C implements short-circuit evaluation on a few operators. One of these is `&&`. This means that if the left hand side of the `&&` evaluates to `false`, then the right hand side will not be evaluated.

Additionally, there is a difference between `++i` and `i++`. `i++` will return `i` and store `i+1`. On the other hand, `++i` will return `i+1` and store `i+1`.

Therefore:

```
int i = -1, j = -1;       // i = -1, j = -1
(i=0)&&(j=0);             // i =  0, j = -1 (right hand side not evaluated because lhs evaluated to 0)
(i++)&&(++j);             // i =  1, j = -1 (right hand side not evaluated because lhs evaluated to 0)
printf("%d, %d\n", i, j);
return 0;
```

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted? If you don't like this thread then vote to close. Personally I don't like the comments too much: I'd prefer i is 0 etc rather than using =.

Comment: Me - Do not feed bad programmers

Comment: +1 Isn't that question interesting, why I am getting downvotes for it? Sorry, but I posted this question to share knowledge, and I think it is not working this way. So I am gonna delete this question. I am sorry for that. @sharth

Comment: @afzalex: As others have mentioned, you're mostly getting downvoted because the code in the question feels generated to be just incomprehensible. Additionally, if you knew the answer to this question, then post the answer yourself. There's no prohibition against doing that.

Comment: You can't delete it as it has an up voted answer. Try improving the question instead.

Comment: So what should I do now? I would give it, I was just waiting if somebody could explain it better than me. And you did that.

Comment: Study something useful like qsort instead.

Comment: The only thing interesting is that a person is able to write incomprehensible code and not be ashamed of it. Some of my poetry is very bad but I use the flame to destroy it

Comment: @EdHeal I didn't write this code. It was asked to me in an online test.

Comment: Are you talking about me? @EdHeal

Comment: @afzalex -You write code that has a narrative, reason and logic to it. You will be able to come back in a year and understand it within the 1/2 hour. This code does not have these properties. So why consider writing such code

Comment: In the test I was given only 30 sec to solve it, and when I discussed this question in chatroom, some peoples with very good repo told me the time limit should be 1 min or 2 min instead. But here you are saying it should be 1/2 hour. I am a learner in C language and I think I should be able to solve this kind of problem in 2 min (or at least 5 min). But I am sorry, I don't mean to make you feel bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61171/discussion-between-afzalex-and-ed-heal).

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of obvious if you consider order of evaluation. The first && only executes the first term. i=0 before && evaluates. The second && also only executes first term as the post fix i++ evaluates to 0, but is incremented to 1. Hence i=1 and j remains unchanged at j=-1.
The best discussion point here is never write code like this, debugging and rationalisation is well tricky.

Comment: You get a +1 for attempting to answer a stupid question

Comment: @EdHeal why are you thinking this is a stupid question. And I wanna clear that I didn't upvoted him, and even the question I asked was not originally created by me, It was asked to me in a good website, when I was giving test in that site.

Comment: @EdHeal Somebody upvoted rhubarbdog because they found his answer useful. You should not say him that. But I would wanna know why you are considering this question to be bad?